# Passing selected cell's label text, return nil when first time (delay in data sent)

Tags: swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm passing the selected cell's label text to another view controller but It will return nil when every first time I select. After that I go back and select again, I will get the previous selected cell's text.Why?

```
var jobDateValueB:String!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jobTime.count //JSON Data from server
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "jobCell", for: indexPath)
    let unixTimestamp = Double(jobTime[indexPath.row])
    let unixTimestamp2 = Double(jobEndTime[indexPath.row])
    let date1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)
    let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp2)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date1)
    let endDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date2)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(strDate) - \(endDate)"

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEdit"{
        let destinationB = segue.destination as? EditTimeTableVC
        destinationB?.passedDataB = jobDateValueB

    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEdit", sender: self)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
    jobDateValueB = currentCell?.textLabel!.text!
}
```

EditTimeTableVC

```
var passedDataB: String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(passedDataB)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAt` method you are calling `self.performSegue` first and then setting  `jobDateValueB`. Try moving `self.performSegue` call to end of the function.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
    jobDateValueB = currentCell?.textLabel!.text!
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEdit", sender: self)
}
```

This should solve your problem but it's not the recommended way. Instead of assigning the selected text value to a class variable you pass it as sender. like this.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
    if let value = currentCell?.textLabel?.text? {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEdit", sender: value)
    }
}
```

And in your `prepare` method you can do.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEdit"{
        let destinationB = segue.destination as? EditTimeTableVC
        if let selectedText = sender as? String {
            destinationB?.passedDataB = selectedText
        }
    }
}
```